# What is this island in the South China Sea called?

Tags: china, identify-this, islands

https://www.google.com/maps/@8.8654585,112.8304113,977m/data=!3m1!1e3

There are a number of islands in the South China Sea that don't have names on Google Maps. There's a list of islands [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_islands_in_the_South_China_Sea) but this is like searching for a needle in a haystack.

I also found another [satellite picture from Microsoft](https://zoom.earth/#view=8.862166,112.836949,15z), but it was too blurry.

I was hoping somebody could identify the island or at least tell me the purpose of it. There are what look like lighthouses, two fields, a helipad, and some other unusual spherical landmarks.

[image: mysterious island]

Comment: The satellite photo you linked to ("from Microsoft") does not look like the image above.  Are you sure it's the same place?

Comment: Are intel agencies now outsourcing their IMINT work to Stack Exchange? :-D

Comment: It is contained within the historical fifty dash line.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Zoom out in the Google Maps pic, the island is on a coral reef. The Microsoft picture is from before there was an island there.

Comment: What the heck is the crop they are growing there ?  Does anyone know?

Comment: @gszavae Your recommendation resulted in success.  Thank you!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This is called [Cuarteron Reef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuarteron_Reef) in English.

It is one of several reefs in the South China Sea that were enlarged and built up around 2015-2016 as part of a land reclamation project by the People's Republic of China.  The structures are apparently of a military nature, including radars and possibly missiles.

The land is also claimed by Taiwan and the Philippines.

It seems unlikely to be a good travel destination at this time.

Comment: Wow that was quick! Thanks. I wasn't thinking of travelling there but I wasn't sure where else to ask.

Comment: `It seems unlikely to be a good travel destination at this time.` 

Comment: *It seems unlikely to be a good travel destination at this time* — unless OP is tasked with the logistics of the People's Liberation Army (PLA) (in which case they may have lost their job by now).

Comment: "It seems unlikely to be a good travel destination at this time." -- Nah, I bet there is no Coronavirus

Answer (score 55):

As a more generic solution, try using Google reverse image search, e.g. in Chrome:

[image]

->

[image]

If using a web browser other than Google Chrome, go to https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch and click on the camera icon:

[image]

Comment: I reverse searched the screenshot you posted about reverse image search, and the result was "screenshot".. smart enough!

Comment: @NeanDerThal 2020-07-20: AI has gained self-consciousness.

Comment: everything is possible in 2020..

Comment: Here I thought that "Let Me Google This For You" answers weren't allowed. ;)

Comment: @nick012000 Travel.SE rule #1: [don't apply rules consistently](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6656/1810)